How do I make Date Components of Horizon Calendar in SwiftUI work with today's date?
Im trying to pass today's date as my start date in my code and every time I try to run a preview my app crashes. Do y'all see what I need to do to fix this?
import SwiftUI
import HorizonCalendar

struct SwiftUIScreenDemo: View {

  // MARK: Lifecycle

  init(calendar: Calendar, monthsLayout: MonthsLayout) {
    self.calendar = calendar
    self.monthsLayout = monthsLayout
    let startDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2023, month: 01, day: 01))!
      print(startDate)
    let endDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2026, month: 12, day: 31))!
    visibleDateRange = startDate...endDate

    monthDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    monthDateFormatter.calendar = calendar
    monthDateFormatter.locale = calendar.locale
    monthDateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(
      fromTemplate: "MMMM yyyy",
      options: 0,
      locale: calendar.locale ?? Locale.current)
  }

I tried breaking all of the individual components down and entering them into the datecompnents as integers and ive tried just adding it ass a date. I've tried the following:
  init(calendar: Calendar, monthsLayout: MonthsLayout) {
    self.calendar = calendar
    self.monthsLayout = monthsLayout

    // Set the start date to today's date
    guard let startDate = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())) else {
        fatalError("Failed to create start date")
    }
    
    // Set the end date to one year from today
    guard let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: startDate) else {
        fatalError("Failed to create end date")
    }

As well as
struct DateComponentDetails {
    let currentYear: Int
    let nextYear: Int
    let currentMonth: Int
    let currentDay: Int
    
    init() {
        let today = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        self.currentYear = calendar.component(.year, from: today)
        self.nextYear = calendar.component(.year, from: calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: today)!)
        self.currentMonth = calendar.component(.month, from: today)
        self.currentDay = calendar.component(.day, from: today)
    }
}

struct SwiftUIScreenDemo: View {

  // MARK: Lifecycle

  init(calendar: Calendar, monthsLayout: MonthsLayout) {
    self.calendar = calendar
    self.monthsLayout = monthsLayout

    let dateDetails = DateComponentDetails()
    
    // Set the start date using today's date components
    let startDateComponents = DateComponents(year: dateDetails.currentYear, month: dateDetails.currentMonth, day: dateDetails.currentDay)
    guard let startDate = calendar.date(from: startDateComponents) else {
        fatalError("Failed to create start date")
    }
    


Read the very basics of SwiftUI. You cannot have eg self.calendar = calendar
without declaring calendar in your View, similarly for the other variables.
